# Downvote link-list answers to questions asking for links?

Tags: discussion, voting, scope, link-only-answers, on-hold

Here's a question where the OP asks for [links to recommended Android game engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26750129/game-engine-for-android). The question has already been put on hold.

There is one answer with a long list of links to game engines. Now I'm wondering: up or downvote this answer, or just to leave it as is? What's the general consensus here, if there is one?

I understand the user put some effort adding the links and summarizing them, which is the kind of response I like to see on SO. So I'd like to reward that.

On the other hand upvoting answers to off-topic questions might encourage others to ask off-topic questions and to answer them. Plus the [usual caveats](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) apply (breaking links etc). So in that light I am considering to downvote.

How would you vote this (or a similar) link-list answer, and why?

Comment: as a 10Ker at another site, first thing I do is vote to delete the question (voting to close if it's not yet). Whether to vote down the answer, depends mostly on whether I want/see the chance for it to be [auto-deleted by roomba](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177675/165773) or whether this will help decrease [amount of del-votes needed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55095/165773). Though, when I see an answer like one in the question you refer, I can't force myself to click down arrow

Comment: There's things at work here that are truly amazing. Wonderful. I had no idea how far automation was taken on SO. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Maybe those links could be in the tag's description? A list like that might be useful for people looking to get into making games. Right now https://stackoverflow.com/tags/game-engine/info is just a wall of text written by someone who seems to think the enter-key will bite if you use it too much.

Comment: Ouch! Never checked that, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 7):

I would personally not vote at all, because i have a conflict between up and down vote.

If it provided an answer to the question, including summarizing the links, it would be upvote worthy. On the other hand, as you mentioned, up voting these kinds of answers can lead to other bad questions being asked, because people see that they get answers.

The question should of course be downvoted.